# SilverStripe composer Upgrade

Tags: php, html, composer-php, silverstripe

I want to update my silverstripe version from 3.1.8 to 4.5 with composer. But when i want to run this code I am getting some weird error. I don't know how i can fix this.

> upgrade-code all --namespace="App\Web" --psr4

But when i run any command with upgrade-code even upgrade-code -v
I am getting this error and I don't know how to proceed with this. I bet something i must change in this commands:

```
composer global require silverstripe/upgrader
composer global config bin-dir
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin/' >> ~/.bash_profile
source  ~/.bash_profile
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```html
tuna@tuna:/var/www$ upgrade-code -v
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Humbug\SelfUpdate\Exception\FilesystemException: The directory is not writeable: /var. in /home/tuna/.composer/vendor/padraic/phar-updater/src/Updater.php:462
Stack trace:
#0 /home/tuna/.composer/vendor/padraic/phar-updater/src/Updater.php(112): Humbug\SelfUpdate\Updater->setTempDirectory()
#1 /home/tuna/.composer/vendor/silverstripe/upgrader/src/Util/UpdateChecker.php(37): Humbug\SelfUpdate\Updater->__construct('', false, 'github')
#2 /home/tuna/.composer/vendor/silverstripe/upgrader/src/Util/UpdateChecker.php(61): SilverStripe\Upgrader\Util\UpdateChecker::getUpdater('1.4.3')
#3 /home/tuna/.composer/vendor/silverstripe/upgrader/bin/upgrade-code(36): SilverStripe\Upgrader\Util\UpdateChecker::getShowNewVersion('1.4.3')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/tuna/.composer/vendor/padraic/phar-updater/src/Updater.php on line 462
tuna@tuna:/var/www$
```

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that my project 3.1.8 is built without the composer and i just copy composer.json from zip from the official site silverstripe 3.1.8 to the project folder hope it will work.

I tried to chmod 775 /home/tuna/.composer/vendor
chmod 775 /home/tuna/.composer/padraic
chmod 775 /home/tuna/.composer/vendor/padraic/phar-updater
But it won't proceed.

Comment: `The directory is not writeable: /var` Seems it's trying to write in /var

Comment: I have made it writable with this command:
sudo chmod 775 /var
and same error poping up. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Where exactly does this command `upgrade-code` come from?

Comment: @NicoHaase it comes from the `silverstripe/upgrader` library